# Converting Y-m-d to a date with a Month name?

Tags: php, date

So I can easily get today's date with:

```
echo (date("Y-m-d"));
```

The above outputs: 2021-12-06

How do I get 2021 December 06 from the above format?

P.S. I will be storing 2021-12-06 into my database. Later I will want to convert this format into the example I gave above.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: this is a generic PHP question, it should have been asked on stackoverflow instead, this stack is for WordPress specific questions

Comment: I've actually tried to do that to this and the follow up Q but the system has closed it instead, it appears some internal auto-moderation rules have kicked in

Comment: Sorry about that guys , my stackoverflow reached max questions. I  know I should of asked there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use createFromFormat to re-format your date. Like so:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2021-12-06');
echo $date->format('Y F d');
```

If you want your output to be anything other than "2021 December 06", please check [PHP datetime formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) for all available formatting options.

Comment: `F` is a full textual representation of a month, `M` is a short textual representation of a month, source [PHP datetime formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php). If you want to get the current datetime with timezone you can use `$date = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('Asia/Jerusalem'));`

Comment: Thanks to both. Actually short textual representation format is what I wanted. Didn't knew it existed.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. I'll edit my answer with the link to the PHP datetime formats for  easy future reference.